# 555 servo controller "modulation input"?

Tags: pwm, 555

Exactly as the question says. On the [TI 555 Rev. C data sheet](http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ds/symlink/lm555.pdf), what is the modulation input for the PWM circuit? Also, can I round the resistor and cap. to 10k and .022uf, respectively?

Answer (score 1):

The modulation input can be used to raise the charging potential for the capacitor. This means if you take pin 5 above where it normally sits (two-thirds Vcc from memory) the frequency will reduce if configured as an astable and the time delay will increase if used as a monostable.

You can round any component value to any other but, whether it will work as you require that's a different story. Show a circuit if you want a more useful answer.